# Is there anyway to get ZodError from refine when we have invalid_type?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, zod

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const Schema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string(),
    description: z.string(),
    startDate: z.coerce.date().refine((date) => date > new Date(), {
      message: "Start date must be in the future",
    }),
    endDate: z.coerce.date(),
    address: z.object({
      detail: z.string().min(1, { message: "Address is required" }),
      cityCode: z.number(),
    }),
  })
  .refine(
    (data) => {
      return data.startDate < data.endDate;
    },
    {
      message: "Start date must be before end date",
      path: ["endDate"],
    }
  );

const data1 = {
  name: "",
  description: "22",
  startDate: "2023-03-01",
  endDate: "2023-02-22",
};

const data2 = {
  name: "",
  description: "22",
  startDate: "2023-03-01",
  endDate: "2023-02-22",
  address: {
    detail: "",
    cityCode: 0,
  },
};

try {
  Schema.parse(data1);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

console.log("_______________");

try {
  Schema.parse(data2);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

I have the schema as above. My problem is that with the `data1`, I can not get the error from `refine` when I don't provide a value for the `address` property, and it results in `invalid_type` error for each property of the `address` object. How do I get the same error as from the `data2` object, without providing a value for `address`. I need that because my `address.cityCode` property is selected from a dropdown list, and it will have the value of `undefined` until the user selects the value.

Comment: Kinda dirty: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shape-yy67ry?file=/src/index.ts - made it optional and then added another refinement to check for it. Let me know if it works for you.